# How does mongoose connect to a remote database server. Can I implement it with http using some protocols

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a basic understanding of how mongoose connect to a local database by passing url, username, password and database. Atlas provides a database as a service that you can connect to mongoose using just a url.

Can I implement an mongodb database sever over http network requests, using node js and any other database (or just using a plain text file). Basically i want to know if there is any protocol that mongodb servers follow.

For example is there a way that I serve mongoose requests like .find({ }) and it uses http API requests. or anything like that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL given by the Atlas to connect to your remote database.

You can use this,

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://Your User_name:${encodeURIComponent(Your Password)}@HOST_Name:PORT/Your DB_Name`)
```

to create a http server, use `http` module.

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('express');
app.set('port', 3000);
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

Comment: I am asking how could I create a http server that I can connect to using mongoose. To try incompetently and not trying to imitate like atlas (Database as a service).